# Python 2.7: Handling wrong input which is not a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am writing a program which is supposed to contain a way of informing the user that the input for one of the variables is not a string, if entered as a name by user.

E.g. program expects a user input of any string, and if it is a string which is contained within dictionary, it will print out its value, if not, it will print out an error message.

```
ageofdeath.getage('JesusChrist')

33

ageofdeath.getage('John McCena')
```

This is not a bible character. Please enter a name of a character from the bible.

but, the program should at least throw an error message when confronted with wrong user input such as

```
ageofdeat.getage(JesusChrist)
```

ideally popping up a message along the lines of "This is not a string please input a string". Instead, no matter whether i try to use `if` `=` or isinstance, it always shows typical python **name is not defined** error. Is there a way of going round this or not really, as it is a default way of *python shell* handling the input?

Comment: What exactly does the user input look like? Do you require them to put quotes around it? If so, you're probably using `input` when you should be using `raw_input`.

Comment: That's not bad input, it's simply a bug in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program isn't even getting to the part where it executes your `getage()` method. It is failing far earlier.

You're using `input()` instead of `raw_input()`. Thus `JesusChrist` is taken as the name of a *variable* because `input()` *evaluates what the user types as a Python expression.* `JesusChrist` is a legal Python variable name, it just hasn't been defined, so Python tells you that. And because it knows you can't do anything with a value that doesn't exist, it stops.

Now you could catch that error by wrapping your `input()` in a `try`/`except` block, but that's just trying to compensate for making the wrong decision in the first place. The right answer is to use `raw_input()` to get input from your user and it will always be a string.